# jQuery tools: open an Overlay manually with a function call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, overlay

I have several "a"-tags on my page that trigger an overlay:

```
<a href="prelevel.htm" rel="#overlay" id="lvl1" style="text-decoration:none"></a>
<a href="prelevel.htm" rel="#overlay" id="lvl2" style="text-decoration:none"></a>
```

Now I want to open one of these overlays with a function-call.
I tried several things and finally came to this solution:

```
function openOverlay(id){
    $("a[id=" + id + "]").overlay().load();
}
```

This works but it seems that with the load() - function all the javascript code on my page is executed again and that causes the destruction of my user interface.

I use this function to create my overlays:

```
$(function() {
      $("a[rel]").overlay({
        api : true,
        mask : '#DCDBDB',
        effect : 'apple',
        onBeforeLoad : function() {
                 var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap");
                     wrap.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));
            }
        });
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you calling [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)?

Comment: Because I read it here: http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/multiple.html (at the bottom)

Comment: Are you trying to write a jQuery Overlay plugin from scratch? Or are you just trying to get the jQuery Tools Overplay Plugin to work?

Comment: I try to get it to work my was. Maybe I should go more into detail. I'm building a game with a state machine and when one level is finished the state machine should be able to open an overlay as a screen between two levels. So I need to have a function I can call to open the overlays and thats what I'm trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

Updated Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("a#lvl1").overlay({
    onBeforeLoad: function() {

    // grab wrapper element inside content
    var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap");

    // load the page specified in the trigger
    wrap.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));

    }
  });

});
</script>

<!-- HTML Link-->
<a href="prelevel.htm" rel="#overlay" id="lvl1" style="text-decoration:none">
    <button type="button">Show external page in overlay</button>    
</a>

<!-- Overlay Container-->
<div class="apple_overlay" id="overlay">
    <div class="contentWrap"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes but I want to open a html file (which I build dynamically) inside the overlay like it is done here: http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/external.html

Comment: Updated my code. The trick is to wrap your triggering element in an anchor and then use the `onBeforeLoad()` method to load the anchor href in the overlay wrap, thus modifying the anchor's behavior.